# Подскажите IDE для PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ide

Подскажите IDE для PostgreSQL, только не pgAdmin. Даже на мощном компе он просто тормоз.

Comment: Если как и многим другим не нравится pgAdmin 4, то ищите адаптированный под новые версии postgres-а pgAdmin 3. Есть как минимум две версии.

Comment: да, мы тоже используем третий, вот эту сборку
 pgAdmin3 LTS by BigSQL 
вполне себе шустренько работает

Answer (score 2):

1. [Database Navigator](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800-database-navigator) (плагин для кучи IDE от тех же авторов) от jetbrains.
2. [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) (IDE) от них же.
3. [Aquafold data studio](http://www.aquafold.com/aquadatastudio.html) (IDE).

Comment: У него pgAdmin тормозит.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev ну что ж мне, еще один инструмент самому написать, что ли :)

Comment: Функциональный как DataGrip и быстрый как psql :)